# Summation indices

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I'm trying to put 2 equations in 1 and get the summation indices in the right place. My code is:

```
\begin{equation}
  \left
    \begin{array}{c}
      \sum_{s \in S} \sum_{e \in E} \sum_{p \in P}
      X_{i}_{e}_{p}_{d}_{s} \ge 1 \\ \\
      \sum_{s \in S} \sum_{e \in E} \sum_{p \in P}
      X_{i}_{e}_{p}_{d+1}_{s} \ge 1
    \end{array}
  \right \} \Rightarrow W_{i}_{d} = 1
\end{equation}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I assume you meant `\left\{` before your array environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is `X_{i}_{e}_{p}_{d+1}_{s}` correct, i.e., are you trying to typeset a term with a quintuple [!!] subscript? Or should it be `X_{i,e,p,d,s}`?

Comment: Please also state what you believe the "right place" for the indexes of summation should be.

Answer (score 1):

Based on guessing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{Bmatrix}
\sum\limits_{s\in S} \sum\limits_{e\in E} \sum\limits_{p\in P}
      & X(i,e,p,d,s)      \ge 1       \\[2.5ex]
\sum\limits_{s\in S} \sum\limits_{e\in E} \sum\limits_{p\in P}
      & X(i,e,p,d+1,s)    \ge 1
    \end{Bmatrix}
\Rightarrow W_{i,d} = 1
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
    \begin{Bmatrix}
\sum\limits_{s\in S} \sum\limits_{e\in E} \sum\limits_{p\in P}
      & X_{i,e,p,d,s}      \ge 1       \\[2.5ex]
\sum\limits_{s\in S} \sum\limits_{e\in E} \sum\limits_{p\in P}
      & X_{i,e,p,d+1,s}    \ge 1
    \end{Bmatrix}
\Rightarrow W_{i,d} = 1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```